# How to construct a jsonb containing a number?

Tags: postgresql-14, jsonb

*Is there a way to construct a jsonb with only a numeric value in it?*

For example,

```
SELECT pg_typeof(('{"a":1}'::jsonb) -> 'a');
```

indicates that `('{"a":1}'::jsonb) -> 'a'` has the jsonb type and it only contains a numeric value `1`.

But how do I create a jsonb with `1` in it *directly* without constructing and destructing an object?

Direct type casting does not seem to work:

```
# SELECT 1::jsonb;
ERROR:  cannot cast type integer to jsonb
LINE 1: SELECT 1::jsonb;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to cast from a string, not from a number: `'1'::jsonb`. This is because using `'1'` means that the result is actually a constant, whereas `1` is a runtime conversion.

`to_jsonb(1)` also works, but I think this uses a runtime conversion.

```
SELECT pg_typeof('1'::jsonb), jsonb_typeof('1'::jsonb);
```

| pg_typeof | jsonb_typeof |
| --- | --- |
| jsonb | number |

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=e60de76843bd07277dcbe651ab835411)